# mongodb get all unique values for each unique field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am looking to query a collection of property prices on mongodb. I would like to return the unique prices only.
There are multiple entries for each property, but I want to return only the unique prices associated with the `propertyID`.

How would I structure the query to remove the duplicate values of `price` for each `propertyID`?

In the table below, there are 5 entries for the price of 400,000, and one for 425,000, for propertyID 752276. I would like to return just the two unique prices, but for all entries in the collection.

[image: excerpt from collection]

To further explain what I am looking for,
If I had the object bellow, I would only want to return `a:{10,20,30},b:{10,20}`

```
a:{10,20,10,30}

b:{10,20,20,20}
```

Comment: Have you checked out [distinct](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)?

Comment: @ray Distinct on its own would return unique values for entire collection, so if two properties had the same price then it would only return one of them. I need it to just remove the duplicates for each propertyID. Please let me know if that needs explained better.

Comment: Are `a:{10,20,10,30}` and `b:{10,20,20,20}` valid objects? ... or did you mean `a:[10,20,10,30]` and `b:[10,20,20,20]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with simple aggregation pipelines

```
{
   $group:{
    "_id": "$propertyID", //Group by property ID,
    "uniquePrices" : {
       "$addToSet" : "$price" //It will give you propertyID wise unique prices
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Gibbs, I was able to adapt your solution to answer my question.